# SharePoint migration tool - "You need to be site collection administrator"

Tags: migration

I am Global Admin on the tenant and site collection administrator on onprem SharePoint2013 .
When I launch SPMT, I can login using my Global Admin O365 credentials for my destination/target.
When I enter sp2013 onprem url, and want to select library (which I plan to migrate), I get login prompt and when I enter credentials get the error : You need to be site collection administrator.
There is no proxy. spmt is installed on updated win 7 workstation not on the SharePoint2013 server.
Any help, ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: I assume - You want to migrate SharePoint On-premise list to Office 365. But when you enter source URL for migration you are getting - site collection admin message, right or the scenario is reversed?

Comment: yes ... I can not connect to on-premise sharepoint 2013 primary site collection. I get the error : You need to be site collection administrator.

Comment: Can you try login into On-premise system using browser and verify that you have access?

Comment: Also check whether there is permission break on list?

Comment: @lovethakker permission breaks are irrelevant to a site collection admin.  A SCA has access to everything, regardless of permissions.

Comment: can we exclude the restriction on authentication methods Microsoft describes in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-the-sharepoint-migration-tool-works ?